# SED delete lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to delete all lines from first to till last occurrence line of matching pattern "1055/Rack2.txt" including this line.
This pattern occurred three times in below data.
Here is the data where I want to work with.

```
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1050/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt
```

I tried with below command, but it deletes only from first line to first occurrence of matching pattern. Deletion not done for next two occurrence.

**sed -i '1,/1055\/Rack2/d' input.txt**

and leaves two lines with same matching pattern and the output is below.

````
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1055/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1100/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1105/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack0.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack1.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt
/root/monitor_data/hmc_temp/2023-01-06-1110/Rack2.txt```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the lines are sorted like that, whay not `sed '/1055/Rack2.txt/d'`?

Answer (score 2):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
printf '%b\n' '?1055\/Rack2?kx' "1;'xd" ,p Q | ed -s input.txt
```

---

A small explanation about the `ed` code.

- First the `printf '%b\n'` is not part of the `ed` code/sysntax, it is a builtin from the shell. See `help printf`
- `?pattern-goes-here?` is the same as `/pattern-goes-here/`, only difference is the search starts from the last line of the buffer. The pattern is `1055/Rack2`. Note the use of `? ?`  instead of `/ /`.
- `kx` Marks the line/string in the buffer, in this case whatever is matched by the `?pattern-goes-here?`, `k` is the command and `x` is the marker.
- `1;'xd` Is an address range separated by a `;` e.g. `start;end` The `1` is the line number, `'x` is how to call/evaluate/expand the marked line/string with `kx` and `d` means delete.
- So in the end it reads *Search the pattern but start from the last line in the buffer and when it matches, marked it with the x marker, then from line number 1, delete until it reaches the spot which is marked and x indeed marks the spot! ;-)*
- If *in-place* editing is required change `Q` to `w`
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

---

- See [GNU ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- See [Posix ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

Comment: Beat me to an ed answer.

Comment: @Shawn, I was playing with reversing the buffer but it still need to mark the spot! so opted without the reversed buffer ;-)

Comment: `printf '%b\n' '1kx' 'g/./m0' "/1055\/Rack2/;'xd" 'g/./m0' ,p Q | ed -s input.txt` , More or less same as the `tac` approach from @steffen

Comment: No need to escape slash when using question marks, and no need to escape question mark when using using slashes. `?1055/Rack2? then. But it's a good habit to always backslash them.

Comment: You welcome @Jetchisel I'm just thinking that there's no need to put a mark: `1,.d` after search from bottom should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for awk:

```
tac test | awk '/1055\/Rack2.txt/{f=1}!f' | tac
```

This command starts printing lines after last match of `/1055\/Rack2.txt/`.

Comment: using `tac` makes the `sed` usable the same too: `tac file | sed '/1055\/Rack2.txt/,$d' | tac` I'm sure there may have a smarter solution with `awk`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;/1055\/Rack2/{z;h};$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Make a copy of the lines before `1055/Rack2` and replace those lines by a newline when the current line is `1055/Rack2`. At the end of the file, remove the newline at the start of the copy and print the remaining lines.

N.B. The `z` GNU command can be replaced by `s/.*//`.

Alternative:

```
sed -z 's#.*1055/Rack2[^\n]*\n##' file
```

The `-z` option slurps the whole file into memory. Since `.*` is greedy it will remove everything upto the last occurrence of `1055/Rack2`. The `[^\n]*\n` removes to the end of that line.

Answer (score 1):

The first `sed` determines the line number of the last occurrence of the regex and the second `sed` deletes relevant lines

```
last=$(sed -n '/1055\/Rack2\.txt/=' file | tail -n1) &&
[ -n "$last" ] &&
sed -i.orig "1,${last}d" file
```